# Custom build eraser brush in fabric js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How to use Custom build in reactjs?
I want to include eraser brush of fabric JS due to which I need to have the custom build as EraserBrush is not present in default build.

I have downloaded the custom build file from http://fabricjs.com/build/ and replaced it with the files under dist folder of fabric under node_modules. But it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.